# Getting mysql wait timeout from php

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to get mysql wait timeout directly from php?

Comment: He wants to know if you can find out from the DB how long its timeout (like max execution time in PHP) is from PHP. @user718480 you will likely need to use some sort of query to the db.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make a normal mysql query.

```
mysql> show variables where Variable_name='wait_timeout';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout  | 28800 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```

In PHP it'd look something like this.

```
// it's been a while to there might be typos
$res = mysql_query("show variables where Variable_name='wait_timeout'");
$arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $arr['Variable_name'];
echo $arr['Value'];
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about that. So I can't get this info without sql-query?

Comment: Your answer is improved updated Feel free to rollback if anything gone wrong