# MySQL Database is timing out

Tags: php

How Do I keep my server from timing out.

I am getting this error and I cannot figure it out:

"mysql server has gone away"

How do you integrate wait_timeout in PHP, if that is my best bet.  How do you handle this type of problem?

Comment: About integration check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740987/getting-mysql-wait-timeout-from-php

Comment: Is it local or production? ie too many users, hungry queries?

Answer (score 0):

This is a natural problem when app and database run in diferent machines or mysql is buzy.
Adjust [mysqli options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php)

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);
```

Comment: Hmm, Where do you put that script?

Comment: In mysql client construction. If you don't use mysqli, edit my.conf and change timeout directives